# Mixed anova post-hoc analysis (when do we need to do t-test across all pairs?)

Tags: anova, mixed-model, post-hoc

before I decided to ask my question, I actually find several existing questions that are very similar to mine but remain unanswered:

[Mixed ANOVA post hoc analysis (and multiple comparisons)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115914/mixed-anova-post-hoc-analysis-and-multiple-comparisons)

[Mixed ANOVA question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406890/mixed-anova-question)

Say for instance:

1. I performed a 2x4 mixed anova with the 4 as within-subject factor.
2. My results showed significant main effect for both between-subject and within-subject factor, but not the interaction.

As asked in the first post, let say we now investigate the between-subject main effects, how do we know if the differences lie in which levels of within-subject factor? It might sounds silly because such thing should correspond to interaction. I also did read some textbooks which say we should interpret the main effects by "collapsing" all other factors?

But then in a real analysis, I encountered similar scneario which I think I can generalize the between-subject main effects to all levels of within-subject factor, **BUT THAT IS NOT THE CASE AFTER I DECIDED TO PLOT THE THINGS OUT AND DO POST-HOC ANALYSIS**.

There is no interaction effect, but the between-subject difference only occurs in certain level of within-subject factor, I am really confused in it, does that mean we need to do post-hoc t test across all pairs all the time when we find a sig. main effects even for no interaction?

any help is appreciated, thanks.